# Are we allowed to apply the chain rule here?

Tags: geometry, chain-rule, fluid-dynamics, frechet-derivative, diffeomorphism

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$ and $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\tau>0$ and $T_t$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$ with $T_0=\operatorname{id}_U$ (assume $[0,\tau)\ni t\mapsto T_t(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$)
- $v_t:T_t(U)\to\mathbb R^d$ with $$v_t\left(T_t(x)\right)=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}T_t(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\tau)\times U\tag1$$
- $\Omega\subseteq U$ and $$\Omega_t:=T_t(U)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,\tau)$$
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $u_t:\Omega_t\to E$ be differentiable

If $$[0,\tau)\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto u_t\left(T_t(x)\right)\tag2$$ is differentiable at $0$ for all $x\in\Omega$, then $${\rm d}u[v](x):=\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}u_t\left(T_t(x)\right)\right|_{t=0}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\Omega$$ is called **material derivative of $u$**. On the other hand, if $$x\in\bigcap_{t\in[0,\:\delta)}\Omega_t\tag3$$ for some $\delta\in(0,\tau]$ and $$[0,\delta)\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto u_t(x)\tag4$$ is differentiable at $0$, then $$u'[v](x):=\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}u_t\left(x\right)\right|_{t=0}$$ is called **local shape derivative of $u$ at $x$**.

> If $u$ has a material derivative and a local shape derivative at $x\in\bigcap_{t\in[0,\:\delta)}\Omega_t$ for some $\delta\in(0,\tau]$, are we able to apply the chain rule and conclude $${\rm d}u[v](x)=u'[v](x)+\left\langle\nabla u_0(x),v_0(x)\right\rangle\tag5?$$

Note that, by $(1)$, $$v_0(x)=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}T_t(x)\tag6.$$

Comment: "$T_t$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$" means that $T_t(x)$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $x$, not with respect to $t$, which appears to be what you were after.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't understand your comment. I know that $T_t(x)$ is differentiable with respect to $x$. And I additionally assumed tat it is differentiable with respect to $t$ as well. But why does this answer my question?

Comment: These are *comments*, not answers. Comments are for improving the quality of the post, not for providing answers. It is a bit jarring that you assume differentiability with respect to one variable, but then through most of the post differentiate with respect to a second variable you hadn't specified was differentiable. However, you are correct that since the existence of $v_t$ is also an assumption, you have implicitly assumed differentiability with respect to $t$. But as a general rule it is more clear to your readers to explicitly assume differentiability before applying the derivative.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Huh? I wrote that the $T_t$ are $C^1$-diffeomorphisms. It's part of the definition of a diffeomorphisms that $T_t$ and $T_t^{-1}$ are differentiable ...

Comment: Saying $T_t$ is $C^1$ means that $T_t(x)$ is differentiable **with respect to $x$, not $t$**.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Exactly! That's why I've wrote (in the highlighted box) "assume $[0,\tau)\ni t\mapsto T_t(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$".

Comment: At the *bottom* you do. By that point, you've already talked about its derivative several times. That is what I am pointing out. As I was reading this - from the top like any normal person - I came across a requirement that $T_t$ should be $C_1$ (with respect to $x$, not $t$). followed immediately by a definition of $v_t(x)$ to be the derivative of $T_t(x)$. That raises a flag, not just for me, but for any competent reader. We now have to track if that unjustified differentiation is a mistaken assumption. Do your readers a favor by showing at the start you know it is necessary, not at the end.